# Django - form wizard step by step

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I'm wondering if someone uses django wizard step by step but with back option? I have form with 5 steps and now it is 'one way form' but I would like to develop it by back option (of course data between steps should be remember). Any idea?

Comment: please share the current solution too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help - http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1454/

Comment: Thank you, this is what I mean. I will try implement it.

Comment: If you found my answer useful - please mark it as correct answer using green tick under the points to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the FormWizard supports this by default when using session or cookie storage.