# How to present a sequence of Django Forms in order?

Tags: python, django, forms

For a questionnaire, I want to present a sequence of forms to the user.  I'd like to keep the view generic, so that it can present any form instance in the sequence.

Currently, I'm storing a list of the form objects (not instances), and I instantiate each form as it needs to be presented. (e.g. `formobject = formslist[3]; form = formobject();`).

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?  I've considered using a `getnext` function in the definition of each form, but I still need a place to list the sequence of forms that I want to generate.

The next step will be to introduce some skip-logic, so hardwiring the form sequence is not ideal.

Maybe this will help.  This is what I have in my view, using a `getnext` function. It works from the first form to the second, but then does not serve the third form:

```
def showform(request):
    if 'formobj' not in locals():
        formobj = StartForm

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = formobj(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
            except:
                pass
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            formobj = form.get_next()
            form = formobj()
            if formobj == 'done':
                render_to_response('doneform.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                form = formobj()
    else:
        form = formobj()

    return render_to_response('template.html', {'form': form, 'requestpath': request.get_full_path()}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)?

Comment: Yes.  I've found the form wizard limited; it does not (as far as I can tell) save the input data from each step on the server.  This is a risk for long forms if the user wants to stop filling out the form and come back later.

Comment: @Ari: have you used django-merlin? do you have some working code to share?

Comment: @brainstorm, I don't recall if I got django-merlin working. For my application, I ended up making a static form based on Adobe FormFiller.

Comment: @Ari: is that a Django app or something outside of django? Thanks

Comment: @brainstorm, it is outside of Django. Adobe has an application to create forms that you can then post online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at this for saving data during form wizard steps

[Using FormWizard and saving the forms data in between before the completion of the whole process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365859/using-formwizard-and-saving-the-forms-data-in-between-before-the-completion-of-t)

Also mentioned in that post is an app called django-merlin which may do what you need. I've not personally used it though.

Edit

Here is another post that might be helpful to you
[Django - form wizard step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811250/django-form-wizard-step-by-step)

Comment: I have looked at both of these, but didn't quite get where I wanted to (or I don't quite understand how to do so).  The first answer does save the data in a serialized format, but it seems like retrieving and unserializing is not trivial.  It also is not clear that this will allow users to move backward in the form. Django-merlin is interesting, but seems to save data to the Session, not on the server side.  I may be wrong about this, but haven't been able to tell from Merlin's docs.

Comment: I now see that Session data *is* stored on the server side.  So it's worth another look--Merlin may be what I need.